# JQuery get classes values inside of classes

Tags: jquery, class, each

I have the following html:

```
<tr class="row">
    <td>row 1</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="user-input"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="user-input"></td>
</tr>

<tr class="row">
    <td>row 2</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="user-input"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="user-input"></td>
</tr>
```

Suppose the form got the following input

row1 | a | b

row2 | c | d

I would like to get the following object from the table:

```
[{a,b}, {c,d}]
```

I have tried to use .each to get the values

```
$(".row .user-input").each( function() {
    ...
});
```

However I can only get [a,b,c,d] by using above lines. I am wondering if there is a way to use some like a nested each for this purpose.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is an array of arrays, then you can iterate of each row then iterate over each input in that row like

```js
var values = $('.row').map(function() {
  return [$(this).find('.user-input').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }).get()];
}).get();

$('pre').html(JSON.stringify(values));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>row 1</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="user-input" value="a">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="user-input" value="b">
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="row">
    <td>row 2</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="user-input" value="c">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="user-input" value="d">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  arr = [];
  $('.row').each(function(o) {
    var inner = [];
    $('.user-input', this).each(function(e) {
      inner.push($(this).val());
    });
    arr.push(inner);
  });
```

-

```
<table>
  <tr class="row">
   <td>row 1</td>
   <td>
     <input type="text" class="user-input" value="a">
   </td>
   <td>
     <input type="text" class="user-input" value="b">
   </td>
 </tr>

 <tr class="row">
   <td>row 2</td>
   <td>
     <input type="text" class="user-input" value="c">
   </td>
   <td>
    <input type="text" class="user-input" value="d">
   </td>
 </tr>

</table>
```

Pen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyYdpq